# Dynamically Load Customer_Name in a ul-li list

Tags: html, asp.net, session, session-variables

I have a page where user Logs In and redirects to the `Home` page, where in i have a ist of `ul's` in a row on top like the general structure of the websites. I am using `<asp:PlaceHolder.../>` where I hide the `<li>` based on if the user is a first-time user or a Logged-In user.

The Code as follows :

```
<ul>
     <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcHldrReg" runat="server">
          <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Home</a>
                 <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="CustomerHome.aspx" style="font-size: medium">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="CustomerLogin.aspx" style="font-size: medium">Login or Sign Up?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="GuestUser.aspx" style="font-size: medium">Sign In as Guest-User</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
          </asp:PlaceHolder>

  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcHldrLogin" runat="server">
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">DynamicUserName</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="CustomerProfile.aspx" style="font-size: medium">Profile</a></li>
                 <li><a href="CustomerHome.aspx" style="font-size: medium">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ul>
```

Code Behind in Master Page :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["existing_user"] != null)
        {
            plcHldrReg.Visible = false;
            plcHldrLogin.Visible = true;
           //Edit : 
           Customer loggedInCustomer = (Customer)Session["existing_customer"];
           lblCustomerName.Text = loggedInCustomer.Name;
        }
    }
```

I want the name of the Customer should be displayed dynamically at `DynamicUserName` .. Is this possible to have a `<asp:Label.../>` where i can assign the dynamically ?

**P.S :** i tried using the `<asp:Label.../>` control but i dont know why the complete `<ul-li>` list gets invisible.

**P.S. :** the session is passed empty to the Home page.. I have put break points on the login page and there Customer object contains all the details , somehow the home page doesnt!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your issue exactly? Dynamically loading of user name or hiding of unordered list?

Comment: @RahulSingh:  Doing both.. One placeholder should hide and other placeholder should contain CustomerName dynamically.. I ve done the first part now i want to load the CustomerName dynamically!

Comment: Where did you assign the value to the label?

Comment: @Mehrdad : please see my updated C# code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in place of `DynamicUserName` place an `<asp:label />` and keep its `Text` property as `Text=""` by default.

and now you can dynamically set the value from c# code based on who has logged in.

```
<li class="has-submenu"><a href="#"><asp:Label ID="DynamicUserName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></a>
```

and you might be storing the `UserID` in `Session` or `QueryString` so from c# you can fire a query with that `UserID` and get Users all information.
now from c# you need to do..

```
if (Session["existing_user"] != null)
        {
            plcHldrReg.Visible = false;
//fire query and get users details
//i suppose you get an Object of 'UserDetails' with one field `UserName` in it

            plcHldrLogin.Visible = true;
DynamicUserName.Text=UserDetails.UserName;
        }
```

This should work fine!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work ..somehow the session contains emty object! Please see my updated question !

Comment: had some mistake in session variables , but this is exactly what i needed! thanks!